# find largest cube in lot of cuboids

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

sorry for my bad English...
I've a system consists of many cuboids, many are adjacent to the others.
My problem is... I want to find the largest cube in this system (which may consists of many of some or all part of the cuboids)

Is there a decent algorithm for finding this ?

Comment: For example... each cuboid defined by x,y,z(it origin)... has length of(Lx,Ly,Lz) which explains it's size.

Comment: This could be better suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/  As is I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: oh! thanks for a fast reply !
I'll do another post at cstheory as you suggested.
Btw, my problem is ... if you have a cuboid starting at(0,0,0) with size(10,10,10)
and another cuboid at(10,0,0) with size(10,10,10)
and another cuboid at(0,10,0) with size(10,10,10)
and another cuboid at(0,0,10) with size(10,10,10)
and another cuboid at(10,10,10) with size(9,9,9)

so, the largest cube in the system will be a cube starting at (0,0,0) with size(19,19,19)

something like that

Comment: I made an mistake!!  Post it on: http://stackoverflow.com/, the other one is for research level CS.  I am not sure how to move questions between stacks.

Comment: Never mind, It's a part of my research topic anyway :)
I'm just want a faster than sweep plane method I have which maintain largest size of square each tip can hold